# Summarizing results from DB table

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table like this:

```
id  |  name  | quantity | price   
================================
1   | milk   |     3    |   3.5
-------------------------------
2   | jam    |     2    |   1.45
--------------------------------
3   | jam    |     1    |   1.45
--------------------------------
4   | milk   |     6    |   3.5
-------------------------------
```

I need to print summarized results for example:

milk - quantity: 9 - price: 3.5 - Sum: 31,5

jam - quantity: 3 - price: 1.45 - Sum: 4.35

NOT LIKE THIS:

milk - quantity: 3 - price: 3.5 - Sum: 10.5

jam- quantity: 2 - price: 1.45 - Sum: 2.9

jam - quantity: 1 - price: 3.5 - Sum: 1.45

milk - quantity: 6 - price: 3.5 - Sum: 21

Here is my code but it gives me not that I want:

```
  $conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','shop') or die ("Fail");
  $sql="select *  from products";
  $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  while ($role=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        extract ($role);
         if ($quantity>0) {
    echo " $name - Price: $price - Quantity: $quantity -  Sum is: ".round($quantity*$price,2)."<br>";
          }  
           else {
               $m[$i]="$name - Price: $price <br>";
               $i++;
           }
  }
```

Help me solve it, please. Thank you :)

Comment: You need to group by name. See: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to modify your code like this:

```
$conn=mysqli_connect('localhost:3310','root','','shop') or die ("Fail");
$sql="select name,sum(quantity) quantity,price,sum(quantity)*price sumAmount  from products group by name,price";
$uspv=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$i=1;

while ($uspm=mysqli_fetch_array($uspv)){
    extract ($uspm);
    if ($quantity>0) {
        echo " $name - Price: $price - Quantity: $quantity -  Sum is: $sumAmount <br>";
    }  
    else {
        $m[$i]="$name - Price: $price <br>";
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by `mysql` query.

`select *,sum(quantity) as total_quantity, round(sum(quantity*price),2) as total_price  from products group by name`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using CONCAT, GROUP BY, ORDER BY no need to use PHP logic any more

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(
 name,"- Quantity :- ",
SUM(`quantity`),"- Price :- ",
price,"- Sum :-", 
SUM(quantity*price)) AS result
FROM grocery GROUP BY name,price ORDER BY name ASC
```

Result:[image]-

Phpmyadmin :-

[image]

Working code for PHP:-

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','DBNAME') or die ("Fail");
$sql  = 'SELECT CONCAT( name,"- Quantity :- ",SUM(`quantity`),"- Price :- ",price,"- Sum :-", SUM(quantity*price))  AS result FROM grocery GROUP BY name,price ORDER BY name ASC';

$result = $conn->query($sql);
$rows   = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
}
```

print using the array:-

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($rows);
```

Result:-

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [result] => jam- Quantity :- 3- Price :- 1.45- Sum :-4.35
    )

 [1] => Array
    (
        [result] => milk- Quantity :- 9- Price :- 3.50- Sum :-31.50
    )

)
```

Comment: Its working well in phpmyadmin, as shown in screen shoot

Comment: yes, it works on phpmyadmin but doesnt work on php program

Comment: let me try on php as well

Comment: copy paste the new cod updated, update your DB details on line 1, its working well. Tested

Comment: scroll down my answer, you will see working code PHP

Comment: everything is the same :) I'll try to fix it. Anyway thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you solve this with SQL only

```
select 
  name, 
  sum(quantity) quantity , price, 
  ROUND(sum(price*quantity),2) as Sum
from 
   products
group by name;
```

Result:

```
name                 quantity                          price        Sum                 
-------------------- --------------------------------- ------------ ------------------- 
jam                  3                                 1.45         4.35                
milk                 9                                 3.5          31.5
```

If you want the result together:

```
select 
   concat(a. name, ' - quantity: ', a.quantity, ' - price: ',  a.price, ' - Sum: ', a.Sum ) resultado
from (
select 
   name, 
   sum(quantity) quantity , price, 
   ROUND(sum(price*quantity),2) as Sum
from 
   products
group by name ) a;
```

Result:

```
resultado                                                                                                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
jam - quantity: 3 - price: 1.45 - Sum: 4.35                                                                         
milk - quantity: 9 - price: 3.5 - Sum: 31.50
```

After this, you can use the PHP code to put the result in a page.

I tested these sql codes.

Hope this helps